# What happen if I don't pay credit card and leave the country

Tags: credit-card, banking, credit, debt

I have a credit card debt of $600, five years ago in Newzealand. I left the country from then, now I live in Singapore.

Will the Newzealand bankers come to Singapore and ask my bank to take money from my bank account and pay them? Although I am using a different bank now.

Comment: You use other people's money and have no intention of paying it back, so in other words you are a thief.

Comment: @Victor: not paying back debts is most definitely not theft. Getting into debt without intention to pay it back may be fraud, though that probably doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt - This is not EnglishUsage.SE, and while you may be technically correct, I believe it's a distinction without a difference.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: it's an important distinction if you believe that justice is more than "I want people to be punished for whatever I feel is wrong".

Comment: If you return to New Zealand, you may be flagged for the unpaid debt. It would be a shame to land in New Zealand and then go directly to jail.

Answer (score 5):

New Zealand Bank cannot directly ask Singapore Bank. They can approach courts in Singapore and request for funds. Given that amount is small, the cost for pursuing a court case in Singapore would be much higher and the Bank in New Zealand may have already written this off.

They may still have reported you as a defaulter, depending on various things, you may not get a Visa to travel back into New Zealand, or get one and get arrested once you land in New Zealand even during transit.

Answer (score 0):

New Zealand has a [statute of limitations](http://www.communitylaw.org.nz/community-law-manual/chapter-12-credit-and-debt/debt-recovery-and-enforcement/) on debt of six years, twelve years if it is "a debt acknowledged in a deed" (probably not the case here). If you have had no contact with the bank for that time, the debt expires.

If you got convicted of a crime in relation to the debt (e.g. fraud) then that would fall under a different statute of limitations, but a bank isn't going to bother doing that over $600, and the courts would probably not accept the case anyway.

Comment: In most countries statute of limitations clock is frozen while the person is out of country.